# Datatables data appending wrongly to the table

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, datatable, datatables

I am having a JSP code to append data into datatables, getting response from another AJAX page, when appending data into the tables, the data is appending very weirdly. I will show it below.

The correct data should be like this:

```
15|3
15|5
16|1
17|2
9|3
```

But instead, i am getting it like this
[image]
/

My JSP code to get the data from the AJAX page

```
htmlrpt = $.ajax({
                    url: <some url> ,
                    method: "GET",
                    async: false,
                    error: function () {
                                alert("Error occured!");
                                        }
                });

var resp = htmlrpt.responseText.replace( /^\s|\r|\n|\s$/g, '').split('|');

var t = $('#dtBasicExample').DataTable({
"ordering": false
});

resp.forEach(function(i){
                        console.log(i);
                        t.rows.add([i]).draw();
                        });
```

Below is the JAVA code that i am appending my Array results into the DT

```
<%
ArrayList<String[]> result = qmv.queryData();
String htarres1 = new String();
    for (String[] paramList : result) {
        for (String htarres2 : paramList){
        htarres1 = htarres1 + htarres2 + ",";
            }
        htarres1 = htarres1.substring(0, htarres1.length()-1);
        htarres1 = htarres1 + "|";
     }
    htarres1 = htarres1.substring(0, htarres1.length()-1);
    out.print(htarres1);
%>
```

In the console, it is showing correctly, but when appending into the table, it is wrong.

Comment: Can you please share sample response which you get from ajax call ?

Comment: This is the response i get in my Firefox console:

Array(10) [ "11,1", "11,2", "11,9", "13,3", "14,2", "15,3", "15,5", "16,1", "17,2", "9,3" ]

Comment: How many columns do you have in Datatable?

Comment: As of now, i have 3 columns in my datatable. I never tried adding additional columns yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have 2 columns your Response data has to be like this

```
{
  "data": [
    [
      "11",
      "1"
    ],
    [
      "11",
      "2"
    ],
    [
      "11",
      "9"
    ],
    [
      "13",
      "3"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Refer [this](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/simple.html) for more detail

Data which you are passing currently will not be treated as a row as it needs to be Array of Array

Comment: i did not fully understand your answer, but i did what they do on the webpage, still no chance solving it

Comment: i am getting this error "DataTables warning: table id=dtBasicExample - Requested unknown parameter '3' for row 0, column 3. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4"

Comment: in my example, i have assumed only 2 columns.  I think you are trying to populate 3 columns in that case Array has to be data : [ [ "a", "b", "c"], [ "1", "2", "3"]  ];

Comment: Great, i manage to solve it, i did some changes to my code which make it back to Array of Array and its now appending accordingly. Thanks for your help